# Download a file from a specific library in Sharepoint

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint

I have a simple console application that upload a file from a local folder to a library in sharepoint, and also have a method that download that folder, but using the url that is activated manually in the web site. But I need to download the same file that I upload a second later, it is for a test, AND WHAT I NEED IS TO ACTIVATE THE "VIEW LINK" FOR DOWNLOAD LATER. Here is my upload method:

```
  static void o365SaveBinaryDirect(ClientContext o365Context, string o365LibraryName, string o365FilePath, string o365FileName) {

        Web o365Web = o365Context.Web;
        if (!LibraryExist(o365Context, o365Web, o365LibraryName)) {
            CreateLibrary(o365Context, o365Web, o365LibraryName);
        }
        using (FileStream o365FileStream = new FileStream(o365FilePath, FileMode.Open)) {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(o365Context, string.Format("/{0}/{1}", o365LibraryName, o365FileName), o365FileStream, true);                
        }
    }
```

Now I have this method that download:

```
 private static void DownloadFile(string webUrl, ICredentials credentials, string fileRelativeUrl) {
        using (var client = new WebClient()) {
            client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
            client.Credentials = credentials;
            client.DownloadFile(webUrl, fileRelativeUrl);

        }
    }
```

I need to generate the url for download the file later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- avoid generating file url based on library title since library url is
  not the same as library title
- since `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect` method from CSOM
  API is used for uploafding a file, consider to utilize [`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.openbinarydirect(v=office.14)) for downloading a file

The following example demonstrates how to upload a file into a library and then downloading it:

```
var sourceFilePath = @"c:\in\UserGuide.pdf";  //local file path;
var listTitle = "Documents"; //target library;

var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
ctx.Load(list.RootFolder);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

var targetFileUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath));

//upload a file
using (var fs = new FileStream(sourceFilePath, FileMode.Open))
{
      Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, targetFileUrl, fs, true);
}

//download a file
var downloadPath = @"c:\out\";
var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, targetFileUrl);
var fileName = Path.Combine(downloadPath, Path.GetFileName(targetFileUrl));
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
{
      fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: Dude, you have no idea what you've helped me with this code, I now understand everything about it, and finished in time, really thx.

Comment: what is 'ctx'? .....